# @Value works without configuring static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to understand the behaviour of @PropertySource annotation when not using @Autowiring and Spring Environment class. I am trying to use @Value to inject values from a properties file at runtime. From the book that I am reading and from the online sources it is required to have a static bean - PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configured in order for this to work. But for me the @Value works without PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer static bean as well. Can someone point me to the right direction as to whats happening here. May be I am missing something very basic. When do we need PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and when not?

Below is the code that I am trying out -

```
package com.nilaysundarkar.demos;

public class Person {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

AppConfig.java -

```
package com.nilaysundarkar.demos;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/nilaysundarkar/demos/app.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    // This bean does not make any difference, or does it?
    /*@Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer(){
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }*/

    @Bean
    public Person person(@Value("${person.name}") String name){
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(name);
        return person;
    }

}
```

Bootstrap -

```
package com.nilaysundarkar.demos;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Person person = context.getBean(Person.class);
        System.out.println(person.getName());
        ((AnnotationConfigApplicationContext)context).close();
    }

}
```

properties file - app.properties -

```
person.name=John Doe
```

pom -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.nilaysundarkar.demos</groupId>
<artifactId>demos-runtime-injections</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I run App.java -

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In spring boot, and spring in general, `application.properties` (and `application.yml` since spring boot) can be placed in `src/main/resources` and it is picked automatically by the spring environment. That means that any property from this files will be loaded to your `Environment` and will be ready for injection using `@Value`.

You can use `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in order to register more property sources like `foo.properties`, `[NAME].properties` and so on in order for the spring `Environment` to add them.

When you use `@PropertySource` you register another propery file to your spring `Environment` so you dont need to use the custom `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to register it again. `@PropertySource` make it easier to register property files that do not require some special loading like a file in your file system etc.

As long as you use the default locations (`application.properties`) you don't need to register a custom `bean` of this type.

**EDIT:**

Example for `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` with the same functionality as `@PropertySource`. The example is based on a `foo.properties` file residing in `src/main/resources`:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("foo.properties"));
    return configurer;
}
```

Comment: So does that mean that I do not need - 

@PropertySource("classpath:/com/nilaysundarkar/demos/app.properties") in the above sample?

When I run without @PropertySource it doesnt work for me - it prints ${person.name} instead of John Doe

Comment: You do, as `app.properties` is not the default place for properties (`application.properties` is the only one that is grabbed automatically).

Comment: Ok. So now I have renamed my property file to application.properties and have placed it under both src/main/resources and my base package. I dont have the @PropertySource since I expect spring to pick up the file by default. This still doesnt work. It prints ${person.name}.

Comment: It might be because you start your application in a different fashion. You should use the spring boot way of loading your context in order to enjoy all the automation spring provide by using `@SpringBootApplication` etc.

Comment: I appreciate the insights into spring's behavior but I am still not sure as to when I need PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer and when not. In the above sample PropertySource worked just fine for app.properties without a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean. app.properties might have been foo.properties and as you said we need a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in such cases. I actually tried the same code above with foo.properties and it still works without PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. Is PropertySource an alternative to PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ?

Comment: `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is used to load property files to your spring `Environment`. It can be used the same way as `@PropertySource` by registering multiple `ClassPathResource` resources. Usualy because this is not complex, you use `@PropertySource` to load from your classpath. Where I work we needed for example to get property files from the user home folder. In this case we used `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in order to register resources from the file system by loading them as resources. Hope it clarify a bit on the usage of `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`

Comment: ok that helps. In the above code sample how would you use PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer (without using PropertySource)?

Answer (score 2):

Took Privotal's *Spring Core* course months ago (probably Feb/2018) and the **student handout** (Version 5.0.a) explicitly tells you that a static `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean must be declared in order for the `${}`placeholders to be resolved when using **Spring Core**. But, when I tested this behavior omitting the creation of the bean in question it worked as If I’d created the bean resolving the placeholders. After that, I contacted my course instructor because I thought there was something wrong with my code, but he later confirmed that my code to be "good". He proceeded to contact Pivotal and we got an *official answer* :

> Properties files registered via @PropertySource **are automatically
>   added** to the Environment in
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClass,
>   SourceClass) while processing @Configuration classes.

So, apparently Pivotal acknowledge that the documentation on this is poor, and have filed a [new JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17212).

BTW, this only applies to **Spring Core 4.3+** as Spring Boot creates this bean for you automatically.

**EDIT:**

If you're taking the certification test, it's not clear when will Pivotal make the update, but the odds of this particular issue showing up on the exam are minuscule (in case it does appears, you can appeal)